# Kotlin class reloading with companion objects/functions

Tags: classloader, kotlin

I'm experimenting with Kotlin class reloading, but I recently got stuck with something close to this:

```
package com.aurieh.reloading
fun doSomething(): String { // a function that does not belong to the class,
    // so it gets compiled as FileName$doSomething$...
}

class FileName {
    // do things with doSomething
}
```

And if I reload this class (with `ImplClassLoader.defineClass` and `ByteArray`), and try do invoke methods that call doSomething internally, I get an error similar to:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.aurieh.reloading.FileName.doSomething$default()Ljava/lang/String; from class com.aurieh.ares.reloading.FileName`
```

I would interpret this as if the reloaded class does not have doSomething attached..
So my question would be, how would I resolve this error? By somehow attaching doSomething to reloading classloader?

For reference, my class reloading code:

```
class Reloader : ClassLoader() {
    fun load(name: String, bytes: ByteArray, offset: Int, len: Int): Class<*> {
        return defineClass("com.aurieh.reloading.$name", bytes, offset, len)
    }
}
```

And for loading:

```
val bytes = File("../classes/path/to/class/FileName.class").readBytes()
Reloader().load("FileName", bytes, 0, bytes.size).newInstance()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, top-level functions are not compiled into any of the classes defined in the file. Instead, a separate class is created for the top-level members: `FileNameKt` (if the file is named `FileName.kt`).

So, to make your class load correctly (i.e. without any unsatisfied links), you have to load the `FileNameKt` class first:

```
val bytes1 = File("../classes/path/to/class/FileNameKt.class").readBytes()
val bytes2 = File("../classes/path/to/class/FileName.class").readBytes()
val reloader = Reloader()
reloader.load("FileNameKt", bytes1, 0, bytes1.size)
reloader.load("FileName", bytes2, 0, bytes2.size).newInstance()
```

Comment: Oh thank you, though I have another problem with it.. If you use lambdas in a class method function, they get compiled as FileName$method_lambda_is_being_called_in$number_of_lambda.class. How would I dynamically check (and load after) for those, if there is a way?

Comment: @Aurieh, I guess you have to override something like `loadClass` in your `ClassLoader` implementation. Once the function using the lambda is called, I see the call to `loadClass(name: String?)` with `name` `com.example.FileName$f$x$1`, i.e. the lambda class name. This comes closer to the concept of class paths: you might want to make your class loader able to load classes from certain paths by their name, and once the class is first used, your implementation will load it.

Comment: Oh, I current have a very dirty implementation of going over all classes at that path, and checking if it starts with my class name plus $, then loading it.. I mean, it works, but its super dirty.. I will take a look at how I could implement your way. But for now, I'm marking this as an answer, thank you!